# PHP Multidimensional array undefined offset error

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Ok, so I have a multidimensional array, represented below. The for loop iterates through it and adds a line to my variable.

`$command` and `$commands` exist. The rest of the function is all correct. My array gets created properly and `$input_filepath` points to a variable that exists.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is occurring. Maybe someone sees what I did wrong? It looks like a simple for loop to me, it just breaks.

**Array `$input_filename`**

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                       [0] => cheque_1.tiff 
                       [1] => cheque_2.tiff 
          ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
                       [0] => supportDoc_1_0.tiff 
                       [1] => supportDoc_2_1.tiff 
                       [2] => supportDoc_1_2.tiff 
                       [3] => supportDoc_2_3.tiff 
                     ) 
      )
```

**Code**

```
for($i=0;$i<count($input_filename);$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<count($input_filename[$i]);$i++)
    {
        $commands .= $command.$input_filepath.$input_filename[$i][$j]." ".rtrim($input_filepath.$input_filename[$i][$j], ".tiff").".jpg\n";
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
Undefined offset: 2
```

The error is pointing to the second for loop.

Any help regarding this issue is greatly appreciated,
thank you

Comment: You have an $i where you should have put a $j. But maybe a foreach loop is more what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably just need to change `$i++` to `$j++` here:

```
for($j=0;$j<count($input_filename[$i]);$i++)
```

Comment: Thank you, I spent hours staring at this.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same value for the variables and editing the incrementor variable for the inner loop it works as intended.

```
$input_filename = array( 
    0 => array ( 
           0 => "cheque_1.tiff",
           1 => "cheque_2.tiff"
        ),
    1 => array ( 
           0 => "supportDoc_1_0.tiff",
           1 => "supportDoc_2_1.tiff",
           2 => "supportDoc_1_2.tiff",
           3 => "supportDoc_2_3.tiff",
        ),
    );

for($i=0;$i<count($input_filename);$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<count($input_filename[$i]);$j++)
    {
        $commands .= $command.$input_filepath.$input_filename[$i][$j]." ".rtrim($input_filepath.$input_filename[$i][$j], ".tiff").".jpg\n";
    }
}

echo $commands;
```